# django form.as_p doesnt render the form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

So here's my form :

```
class SecretNoteForm(forms.Form):
    note = forms.Textarea()
```

Here's my view :

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass
    else:
        form = SecretNoteForm()

    return render(request, "notes/index.html", {"form" : form})
```

and my html :

```
{% block content %}
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Create">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

When I go to the url it only shows me Create button but no form fields. What am I doing wrong here ? I can't seem to figure that out..

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to make a TextArea is with a widget:

```
note = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Here is more documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/

and include attributes like that:

```
note = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 16,'cols': 25}))
```

Comment: You are right: `froms.Textarea` isn't a formfield. It's a widget. These are valid formfields: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/fields/#built-in-field-classes. Don't point to modelforms the OP question is about a normal form.